Precise definition for uniformly convex domains
I am reading some papers about optimal transport, and I can not find a reference for the definition of "uniformly convex domain". I have tried to google it, but I can only find uniformly convex Banach spaces, which is not what I want.
For an example of using "uniformly convex domain", here is a paper: $C^{2, \alpha}$ regularity of free boundaries in optimal transportation by Shibing Chen, Jiakun Liu, Xu-Jia Wang (https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.10503). In page 2 Theorem 1.1 says "Let $\Omega, \Omega^\ast \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two separate, uniformly convex domains with ...". In the same paper, on page 13, the author says that by the $C^2$ regularity and
uniform convexity of $\partial \Omega^\ast$, we also have
$$
\frac{1}{C}|y^\prime|^2 \leq \rho^\ast(y^\prime) \leq C|y^\prime|^2,
$$
where $\partial \Omega^{\ast}$ can be seen as the graph of $\rho^\prime$ over $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, and $y^\prime \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. So it seems that uniformly convexity means $ \frac{1}{C} \leq \nabla^2 \rho \leq C$ here. Is this related to the definition? And what is the definition if the boundary is not $C^2$?
In summary, my question is: What is the precise definition of "uniformly convex set"? Where can I find a reference for this definition?

In that paper, uniform convex just means what you wrote, namely, $\frac{1}{C}I\leq\nabla^2\rho\leq CI$ at each boundary point. In other words, the principal curvatures of the domain are bounded from below by some positive constant.

Thank you for your answer! I'm new to here and I'm so glad to see your answer. :) And do you know any reference(books, thesis, etc) for the definition of uniformly convex? I have read "definitions" like what you have said in other answers, which says the principal curvatures are bounded from below, but I never find a solid reference.
